# How to install packages with PEAR or PYRUS: nothing works

Tags: xml, package, pear, pyrus

Numerous options for installing a package fails.  Tried just now to install the package manager

```
$ pear install --onlyreqdeps PEAR_PackageFileManager
```

Only to get

```
Access is denied.
```

Tried to use pyrus, but I get

```
Pyrus\XMLParser\Exception: Invalid XML document
 Pyrus\XMLParser\Exception: Line 2: Element '{http://pear2.php.net/dtd/customcommand-2.0}commands', attribute 'version': The value '(null)' does not match the fixed value constraint '2.0'.
```

This is a circular dependency: I need the package file manager to create the packages.XML file, but I can't get the package manager if I don't have a packages.XML file for pyrus.  This is not workable.

Lastly, the pear manual describes how to generate a packages.xml file.  There's a link to a template that the document says to use.  When I click on that link, I get a file not found error.

Am having other failures, but the summary is that even carefully following the PEAR manual in detail doesn't create a workable PEAR.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I note that someone has said I've done little research (-1).  I've been working on this for at least a week, almost full time.  Pear works, and all I want to do, ultimately, is add the Mail package.  I'm happy to do more research, I need a pointer because what I've read thus far is difficult.  If the individual who marked my question down would provide a better pointer, I'm happy to learn on my own.  Yes, this is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like a bit of anger-frustration to get the ball rolling.  I found the answer here: http://davehiren.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-or-uninstall-pear.html.  Thank goodness for Dave Hiren!  I did config-set on all the path variables and voila!  The mail package loaded just fine.  Case closed.